# How to correctly test if NgModelGroup is valid?

Tags: angular

I have group of inputs on my form wrapped in `ngModelGroup` like so:

```
<div #myGroup="ngModelGroup" ngModelGroup="myGroup">
  <input name="first"  someAsyncValidator />
  <input name="second" someAsyncValidator />
</div>
```

Then in my code I'm trying to get `myGroup.valid` when I click a button, but, as I figured, it is actually in `pending` status.

How do I correctly *wait* for all validators to be done to see the actual result for current values?

Answer (score 0):

```
valid? {{ myHistoryGroup.valid }}
<div ngModelGroup="address" #myHistoryGroup="ngModelGroup">
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="address.first" name="first" />
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="address.second" name="second" />
</div>
```

use it like this